# Vanilla JS, radioButton cannot be "found" with getEl...ById()

Tags: javascript, dom, module

So here is my problem:
I do an online vocabulary-trainer, i am currently working on a Widget, where the user can get an overview about all his vocabulary-Sets.

In main.js, there is a button, that makes the user show the overview.The eventListener is made in a way that, if you HAVE cards, the window in question generates new HTML throughout a method of another Module.

This is main.js:

```
buttonVokabelsetsAnzeigen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (sprachenArray.length > 0) {
    imBearbeitungsfensterVokabelnBearbeiten.style.transform = "translateX(-25%)";
  }
  setsAnzeigenZeileMitSprache.innerHTML = vokBearbeitenInterface.erstelleZweiteZeileBeiVokabelsets();
  setsAnzeigenZeileMitVokabeln.innerHTML = vokBearbeitenInterface.erstelleDritteZeileBeiVokabelsets();
});
```

and this is the code from the other module:

```
erstelleDritteZeileBeiVokabelsets() {
    if (sprachenArray.length === 0) {
      return `<h3>Erstelle eine neue Sprache, der du dann Vokabeln hinzufügen kannst</h3>`;
    } else if (sprachenArray.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Die erste Sprache wird angezeigt: ${sprachenArray[0].wirdAngezeigt}`);
      if (sprachenArray[this.angezeigteSpracheIndex()].vokabeln.length === 0) {
        return `<h3>Du hast noch keine Vokabeln in dieser Sprache<br>Drücke unten auf das PLUS, um Vokabeln zu erstellen</h3>`;
      } else {
        return `<a href="#">&#x21F1;</a>
                <div id="wrapperFuerVorschauVokabelnWoerter">
                    <div class="vorschauVokabelfuerMenus vorschauVokabelnWoerter" id="vorschauVokabelWortLinks"><div class="vorschauVokabelHintergrundLinien"><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr></div></div>
                    <div class="vorschauVokabelfuerMenus vorschauVokabelnWoerter" id="vorschauVokabelWortHaupt">
                        <div id="vorschauVokabelInterface">
                            <div id="wrapperFuerEditLoeschen">
                                <div id="editLoeschenCon">
                                    <button class="vorschauVokabelnButtons" id="vorschaubuttonVokabelBearbeiten">&#x1F6E0;</button>
                                    <button class="vorschauVokabelnButtons" id="vorschaubuttonVokabelLoeschen">&#x1F5D1;</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="wrapperFuerLevelRadiosInVorschau">
                                <div id="levelRadiosVorschauCon">
                                    <input type="radio" class="vorschauVokabelWortAlleRadios" id="vorschauRadioProfi" name="vorschauRadioGruppe" />
                                    <input type="radio" class="vorschauVokabelWortAlleRadios" id="vorschauRadioModerat" name="vorschauRadioGruppe" />
                                    <input type="radio" class="vorschauVokabelWortAlleRadios" id="vorschauRadioMittel" name="vorschauRadioGruppe" />
                                    <input type="radio" class="vorschauVokabelWortAlleRadios" id="vorschauRadioAnfaenger" name="vorschauRadioGruppe" />
                                    <input type="radio" class="vorschauVokabelWortAlleRadios" id="vorschauRadioSchlecht" name="vorschauRadioGruppe" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vorschauVokabelHintergrundLinien"><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr></div>
                        <div id="wrapperFuerWortBezeichner">
                            <p class="vorschauVokabelSpracheGross">${sprachenArray[0].vokabeln[0].getDeutschesWort()}</p>
                            <p class="vorschauVokabelSpracheKlein">${sprachenArray[0].vokabeln[0].getFremdesWort()}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vorschauVokabelfuerMenus vorschauVokabelnWoerter" id="vorschauVokabelWortRechts"><div class="vorschauVokabelHintergrundLinien"><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr></div></div>
                </div>
<a href="#">&#x21F1;</a>`;
```

now i want to make sure, that if the level of the word is 4 (or any other), you can already see it on this overview within those radiobuttons(and if wanted, change it)
thats why i started to get one of those buttons with

```
let vorschauProfi = document.getElementById("vorschauRadioProfi");
```

but it is null??

how the hell can it be null?
I want to refer it into the "let vorschauProfi" variable AFTER i created the HTML, so its already in the DOM before i want to use it. I can even pick it with the developing tools of my browser where it is even shown with the same id, just as i would have created that radiobuttons in my HTML-File.

What am i missing here?

[radiobuttons and the "null" within console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5VFi.png)

Comment: impossible to really guess with what is provided. I assume you are trying to find the element before it is on the page.

Comment: no i didnt...i just found he problem:

there seems to be adifference between returning html-element-objects with "XYZ.innerHTML" and creating them with "document.createElement" regarding the DOM-Accesibility.

after using createElement it worked!!!